# Load plugins'.mo and .po files from a directory

Tags: plugins, translation

What I'm trying to do is simple: I have so much WordPress plugins, and 3/4 of them aren't translated in my language, so I want and can translate them all without problems, but I would insert translations inside a directory, so everytime I update plugins I don't have to re-upload in every plugins folder the translation... 
Could this in some way be achieved? 
It's like as a **child theme** works; so if you insert for example, *header.php* in child theme, WordPress will load code from there. 
Practically I would create a directory like **wp-content/translations/name-of-plugin/en.mo**; exists any way to tell WordPress to use that directory to take translations? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is, in fact, already available by default. If specific locale isn't available in plugin's folder WordPress will try to fallback to languages directory.

It is defined by `WP_LANG_DIR` constant and for plugins the default location would be `wp-content/languages/plugins`. Note that name is expected to follow the specific format: `name-locale.mo`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So, for example I have the plugin "Stackoverflow WP" and the slug of this plugin is "stackoverflow-wp", and I want to translate it in Italian, it's enough to place the translation in this way: **wp-content/languages/plugins/stackoverflow-wp-it.mo**? I thought that this could be available by default but I didn't find any information about, online... Thank you again!

Comment: Locale part should be in full, I think that would be `it_IT`.

Comment: Oh okay, I haven't put it because Italian usually doesn't have the full locale part. In fact, in HTML declaration in Italian we use just "it"! Thank you, anyway! So the path is correct?

Comment: Yes, as per answer that should work. :)

Comment: Perfect. Thank you! Now I don't have time, but tomorrow I will try and let you know. Sorry if I can't vote up your answer, but I need more reputation to do so. Meanwhile, it I marked your answer as solving. I hope it will work. Thank you again! :)